# how to instantiate a model whose name is obtained dynamically from database in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the model name saved in my database. I obtain it using certain query. Now I need to hold the name of model in certain kind of variable and instantiate it dynamically.So that I can use it for further processing. I want something like this. Please help!

```
public string Checker(int Id)
{
    var dataContext = new PetaPoco.Database("MessageEntity");
    var jsonOLD = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<OldData>("Select OldJson from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
    var jsonNEW = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<NewData>("Select NewJson from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
    var modelName = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<NameOfModel>("Select ModelName from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);

    MakerCheckerModel mcmodel = new MakerCheckerModel();

    mcmodel.OldJson = jsonOLD.OldJson;
    mcmodel.NewJson = jsonNEW.NewJson;
    mcmodel.ModelName = modelName.ModelName;
    var modelname = mcmodel.ModelName;


    UserModel olduser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(mcmodel.OldJson);
    //The way usermodel is hardcoded here. I need it to be dynamic. So that It can work for several data.Something Like this.
    mcmodel.ModelName olduser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mcmodel.ModelName>(mcmodel.OldJson);
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: You'd have to have something like a dictionary containing the string you get back from the DB, and the method instantiation. That way you can instantiate the related method by the string dynamically.

Comment: @SemiDemented can you help me with simple example

Comment: If my answer helps, then mark it as answered so it can help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this In this way.

```
  public string Checker(int Id)
    {


        var dataContext = new PetaPoco.Database("MessageEntity");
        var jsonOLD = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<OldData>("Select OldJson from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
        var jsonNEW = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<NewData>("Select NewJson from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
        var modelName = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<NameOfModel>("Select ModelName from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);

        MakerCheckerModel mcmodel = new MakerCheckerModel();

        mcmodel.OldJson = jsonOLD.OldJson;
        mcmodel.NewJson = jsonNEW.NewJson;
        mcmodel.ModelName = modelName.ModelName;
        var modelname = mcmodel.ModelName;
        string fullName = "MessageCompose.Models." + modelname;
        Type type = Type.GetType(fullName);
        Object obj = (Activator.CreateInstance(type));

        dynamic olduser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(mcmodel.OldJson,obj.GetType());
        dynamic newuser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(mcmodel.NewJson,obj.GetType());
}
```

Thanks to all who helped.It may help others

Answer (score 0):

You need to store full name of your model (Namespace.ModelName).

```
 var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("NameSpace.Model"));
```

Hope this help.

Check this [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XcACZQ)

Let me know if you still face any issues

**Update:**
Let say this is your code.

```
var dataContext = new PetaPoco.Database("MessageEntity");
var jsonOLD = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<OldData>("Select OldJson from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
var jsonNEW = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<NewData>("Select NewJson from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
var modelName = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<NameOfModel>("Select ModelName from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
```

Now you can create instance of your model this way.

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(modelName)); //(Make sure your modelName include namespace eg. NameSpace.ModelName)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But how can I hard code the model name inside"NameSpace.Model" as I get the name of model dynamically from db this way.   var modelName = dataContext.SingleOrDefault<NameOfModel>("Select ModelName from MakerChecker2 where MakerCheckerId=@0", Id);
   I hope I understood what you are suggesting.

Comment: yes I checked the modelName includes name space but var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(modelName)); says invalid arguments Type.GetType requires string arguments. I cant simply pass my variable

Comment: I am still stuck over here someone please help